# How to resize the panel at runtime in asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have use Panel control in my web application.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlSearchMaterialAllowance">...</asp:Panel>
```

here, I want user can change the height and width of this panel at runtime and its controls will adjust as per change.
**Is it Possible?**

if yes then how to do that? with VS2010 ,IE8

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I assume you have a click event set so when a user clicks a button the event fires. I have done this in a project I am currently working on. In code behind method

```
DivClassOrID.Attributes.Add("style", "width: 50px; height:50px;");
```

This also works for panels and divs. you can easily insert the user input ranges with a string variable.

```
string userInputX = txtUserInputX.text;
string userInputY = txtUserInputY.text;
DivClassOrID.Attributes.Add("style", "width:" + txtUserInputX + "px; height:" +
              userInputY + "px;");
```

Comment: Then what you may need is a realizable panel. I have found several articles that show it can be done with JQuery and Ajax. Try this linkhttp://juiceui.com/controls/resizable

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. The above link works only with <div> id , not for panel id. Also after post back it will not working any more.

Comment: The only advice I have left is to maybe use a hidden label on the screen that holds the last value given when the user alters the panel. Sorry I can't be more helpful. With enough persistence you will find a way.

Comment: Try this piece of code using a hidden asp: label to hold the last value. http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?450988-How-do-I-resize-a-panel-at-runtime